# How do I update values in a nested array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

*I would like to preface this with saying that english is not my mother tongue, if any of my explanations are vague or don't make sense, please let me know and I will attempt to make them clearer.*

I have a document containing some nested data. Currently `product` and `customer` are arrays, I would prefer to have them as straight up ObjectIDs.

```
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bab713622c97440f287f2bf"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2018-09-26T13:44:54.431Z"),
            "prod_line" : ObjectId("5b878e4c22c9745f1090de66"),
            "entries" : [
                    {
                            "order_number" : "123",
                            "product" : [
                                    ObjectId("5ba8a0e822c974290b2ea18d")
                            ],
                            "customer" : [
                                    ObjectId("5b86a20922c9745f1a6408d4")
                            ],
                            "quantity" : "14"
                    },
                    {
                            "order_number" : "456",
                            "product" : [
                                    ObjectId("5b878ed322c9745f1090de6c")
                            ],
                            "customer" : [
                                    ObjectId("5b86a20922c9745f1a6408d5")
                            ],
                            "quantity" : "12"
                    }
            ]
    }
```

I tried using the following query to update it, however that proved unsuccessful as Mongo didn't behave quite as I had expected.

```
    db.Document.find().forEach(function(doc){
            doc.entries.forEach(function(entry){
                    var entry_id = entry.product[0]
                    db.Document.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set:{'product': entry_id}});
                    print(entry_id)
                    })
    })
```

With this query it sets `product` in the root of the object, not quite what I had hoped for. What I was hoping to do was to iterate through entries and change each individual `product` and `customer` to be only their ObjectId and not an array. Is it possible to do this via the mongo shell or do I have to look for another way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to accomplish your specified behavior, you just need to modify your query structure a bit. Take a look [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-elements-in-arrays) for the specific MongoDB documentation on how to accomplish this. I will also propose an update to your code below:

```
db.Document.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.entries.forEach(function(entry, index) {
        var productElementKey = 'entries.' + index + '.product';
        var productSetObject = {};
        productSetObject[productElementKey] = entry.product[0];
        db.Document.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set: productSetObject});
        print(entry_id)
    })
})
```

The problem that you were having is that you were not updating the specific element within the `entries` array, but rather adding a new key to the top-level of the document named `product`. Generally, in order to set the value of an inner document within an array, you need to specify the array key first (`entries` in this case) and the inner document key second (`product` in this case). Since you are trying to set specific elements within the `entries` array, you need to also specify the index in your query object, I have specified above.

In order to update the `customer` key in the inner documents, simply switch out the `product` for `customer` in my above code.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add a property 'product' directly into your document with this line

```
db.Document.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set:{'product': entry_id}});
```

Try to modify all your entries first, then update your document with this new array of entries.

```
db.Document.find().forEach(function(doc){
        let updatedEntries = [];
        doc.entries.forEach(function(entry){
            let newEntry = {};

            newEntry["order_number"] = entry.order_number;
            newEntry["product"] = entry.product[0];
            newEntry["customer"] = entry.customer[0];
            newEntry["quantity"] = entry.quantity;

            updatedEntries.push(newEntry);
       })
       db.Document.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set:{'entries': updatedEntries}});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to enumerate all the documents and then update the documents one and a time with the value store in the first item of the array for product and customer from each entry:

```
db.documents.find().snapshot().forEach(function (elem) {
    elem.entries.forEach(function(entry){

        db.documents.update({
                _id: elem._id,
                "entries.order_number": entry.order_number
            }, {
                $set: {
                    "entries.$.product" : entry.product[0],
                    "entries.$.customer" : entry.customer[0]
                }
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Instead of doing 2 updates each time you could possibly use the [filtered positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to do all updates to all arrays items within one update query.